# Решение задачи на СИ

Tags: c

Задача состоит в том, чтобы программа считывая acii знаки, нашла среди них значения принадлежащие шкале Цельсия и перевела их в значения по Фаренгейту. Например, если 9237492572vcs 100C msdaa aw 0C, то должно считаться только 100С 0С и вывести 212F 32F. Значения на вход подаются рандомные. **Запрещено использовать массивы, указатели и явные числовые коды ascii-знаков**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int c_f(int celsius)
{
    return ((celsius * 9) / 5) + 32;
}

int in_alphabet(char c)
{
   return (c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c == 'C');
}

int main(void)
{
char symbol;
int fahrenheit;
int state = 1;
char celsius;

while ((symbol = getchar()) != EOF) {
    switch(state) {
        case 1:
            if (in_alphabet(symbol)) {
            scanf("%d", &celsius);
            fahrenheit = c_f(celsius);
            state = 1;

            } else if (!in_alphabet(symbol)) {
                state = 1;
            }
            printf("%d%s", fahrenheit, "F");
            break;
    }
}
   return 0;
}
```

Сейчас цикл проходит по каждому символу и выводит вместо него 32F. Вместо считывания celsius присваивает ему 0. Цикл игнорирует нули, при 100С проходит по 1 и С. Как это исправить?
Как сделать чтобы цикл считывал слово полностью, при этом не в 16чной системе счисления?(сейчас 100С - воспринимает как 4108)

Comment: В чем глубинный смысл присваиваний `state = 1`, если `state` с самого начала оавно 1 т всегда и везде делается только `state = 1`?

Answer (score 2):

Считать можно так (перевести сам сможешь):

http://ideone.com/ThL4Zy

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    char s[2];

    while (1)
    {
        switch (scanf("%d%1[C]", &x, s))
        {
            case -1:
                return 0;
            case 2:
                printf("%d\n", x);
                break;
            default:
                scanf("%*[^-+0-9]");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то сложно всё у вас :) Два варианта с разными подходами. Первый работает со входной строкой, поэтому есть возможность использовать `atoi()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

static void c_f( int celsius )
{
    printf( "%4dC => %.2fF\n", celsius,
            ( ( ( double )celsius * 9.0 ) / 5.0 ) + 32 );
}

int main( void )
{
    const char data[] = "2C9237492572vcs 100C msdaa aw 0C";
    const char *ptr = data;

    while( *ptr ) {
        /* ищем цифру */
        while( *ptr && !isdigit( *ptr ) ) {
            ptr++;
        }

        if( *ptr ) {
            /* запомнили позицию первой цифры */
            const char *start = ptr;

            /* пропускаем всё до не-цифры */
            while( isdigit( *ptr ) ) {
                ptr++;
            }
            /* после цифр стоит 'C' - нашли, выводим */
            if( *ptr == 'C' ) {
                c_f( atoi( start ) );
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
   2C => 35.60F
 100C => 212.00F
   0C => 32.00F
```

Второй работает с посимвольным чтением потока и формирует число (`celsius`) на лету:

```
int main( void )
{
    int c;

    while( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF ) {
        /* ищем цифру */
        while( c != EOF && !isdigit( c ) ) {
            c = getchar();
        }

        if( c != EOF ) {
            int celsius = 0;
            /* пропускаем всё до не-цифры */
            /* параллельно формируем число */
            while( 1 ) {
                celsius += ( c - '0' );
                c = getchar();   
                if( isdigit( c ) ) {
                    celsius *= 10;
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            /* после цифр стоит 'C' - нашли, выводим */
            if( c == 'C' ) {
                c_f( celsius );
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Сложно как-то...

Comment: @Qwertiy, есть варианты проще? Во всяком случае с потоком ничего умней (и одновременно надёжней) в голову не пришло :)

Comment: Я ж вроде ответом запостил :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, а :) Просто у меня мысль начала от строки отталкиваться. А как тут обойтись `sscanf` не придумал, потому и с потоком уже забил :)

Answer (score 0):

Простое решение.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int c_to_f(int celsius)
{
    return ((celsius * 9) / 5) + 32;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char string[] = "9237492572vcs 100C msdaa aw 0C";
    char seps[]   = " ";
    char *token;

    /* выделям токены. разделител - ' ' */
    token = strtok( string, seps );
    while( token != NULL )
    {
        /* выводим на экран чтобы убедиться что прочитано */
        printf( "token: %s\n", token );

        /* читаем число и после него символ C */
        int t_in_c;
        if (sscanf(token, "%dC", &t_in_c) > 0)
        {
            /* если прочитано удачно то выводит результаты и преобразование */
            printf( " %d => %d\n", t_in_c, c_to_f(t_in_c) );
        }
        /* читаем следующий токен */
        token = strtok( NULL, seps );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Код некорректно работает с вашими же данными. И в этой строке он ничего не найдёт: `"ab123Cd"`.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.