# Проблема с чтением чисел

Tags: c

Изначально стояла задача из входного потока данных выискивать определенные значения и переводить их из цельсия в фаренгейты. Цель была все таки достигнута, но появилась проблема. Если кол-во знаков в числе превышает 7, то число переводится совершенно неправильно. Например, при переводе числа 44586487 должно выводиться 80255709, но выводит 80255712, будто бы изначальное число было 44586489. Скидывали статьи на limits.h и дополнительный код, но не могу понять как с этим связана проблема.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int all(char c)
{
    return !(isdigit(c) || c == ' ' || c == 'C' || c == '\n' || c == '-' || c == '+');
}

float c_f(double c)
{
    return (c * 9) / 5 + 32;
}

int tabn(char c)
{
    return !(c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c == '-' || c == '+');
}

int main(void)
{
    int symbol;
    float m = 0.0;
    float s = 0.0;
    int state = 0;
    float f = 0.0;
    float r = 0.0;
    long int l = 0;
    long int k = 0;

while ((symbol = getchar()) != EOF) {
    switch (state) {
        case 0:
            if (symbol == ' ' || symbol == '\n' || symbol == '\t') {
                state = 0;
            } else if (symbol >= 'a' && symbol <= 'z') {
                state = 9;
            } else if (symbol == 'C') {
                state = 1;
            } else if (symbol >= 'A' && symbol <= 'Z') {
                state = 9;
            } else if (symbol >= '0' && symbol <= '9') {
                m = (s * 10) + (symbol - '0');
                s = m;
                state = 1;
            } else if (symbol == '-') {
                state = 8;
            } else if (symbol == '+') {
                state = 0;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if (isdigit(symbol)) {
                m = (s * 10) + (symbol - '0');
                s = m;
                state = 11;
            } else if (symbol == 'C') {
                f = round(c_f(s));
                l = f;
                r = l;
                state = 3;
            } else if (all(symbol)) {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 2;
            } else if (symbol == ' ' || symbol == '\t') {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 12;
            } else if (symbol == '\n') {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 7;
            } else if (symbol == '-') {
                state = 8;
            } else if (symbol == '+') {
                state = 0;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (all(symbol)) {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 2;
            } else if (symbol == ' ') {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 1;
            } else if (symbol == '\n') {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                printf("\n");
                state = 7;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if (symbol == ' ' || symbol == '\t') {
                printf("%ld%s", l, "F ");
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 0;
            } else if (tabn(symbol)) {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 2;
            } else if (symbol == '\n') {
                printf("%ld%s\n", l, "F ");
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 7;
            } else if (symbol == '+') {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 2;
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            if (isdigit(symbol)) {
                m = (s * 10) + (symbol - '0');
                s = m;
                state = 11;
            } else if (symbol == 'C') {
                f = round(c_f(s));
                l = f;
                r = l;
                state = 5;
            } else if (all(symbol)) {
                state = 2;
            } else if (symbol == ' ' || symbol == '\t') {
                state = 12;
            } else if (symbol == '\n') {
                state = 7;
            } else if (symbol == '-') {
                state = 8;
            } else if (symbol == '+') {
                state = 0;
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            if (symbol == ' ' || symbol == '\t') {
                printf("%ld%s", l, "F ");
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 1;
            } else if (tabn(symbol)) {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 2;
            } else if (symbol == '\n') {
                printf("%ld%s\n", l, "F ");
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 7;
            } else if (symbol == '+') {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 2;
            }
            break;
        case 6:
            if (isdigit(symbol)) {
                m = (s * 10) - (symbol - '0');
                s = m;
                state = 10;
            } else if (symbol == 'C') {
                f = round(c_f(s));
                l = f;
                r = l;
                state = 3;
            } else if (all(symbol)) {
                state = 2;
            } else if (symbol == ' ' || symbol == '\t') {
                state = 13;
            } else if (symbol == '\n') {
                state = 4;
            } else if (symbol == '-') {
                state = 8;
            } else if (symbol == '+') {
                state = 0;
            }
            break;
        case 7:
            if (symbol == ' ' || symbol == '\n' || symbol == '\t') {
                state = 7;
            } else if (symbol >= 'a' && symbol <= 'z') {
                state = 9;
            } else if (symbol == 'C') {
                state = 4;
            } else if (symbol >= 'A' && symbol <= 'Z') {
                state = 9;
            } else if (symbol >= '0' && symbol <= '9') {
                m = (s * 10) + (symbol - '0');
                s = m;
                state = 4;
            } else if (symbol == '-') {
                state = 8;
            } else if (symbol == '+') {
                state = 0;
            }
            break;
        case 8:
            if (symbol >= '0' && symbol <= '9') {
                m = (s * 10) - (symbol - '0');
                s = m;
                state = 6;
            } else if (symbol == ' ' || symbol == '\n' || symbol == '\t') {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 8;
            } else if (symbol >= 'a' && symbol <= 'z') {
                state = 9;
            } else if (symbol == 'C') {
                state = 8;
            } else if (symbol >= 'A' && symbol <= 'Z') {
                state = 9;
            } else if (symbol == '-') {
                state = 9;
            } else if (symbol == '+') {
                state = 0;
            }
            break;
        case 9:
            if (symbol == ' ' || symbol == '\n' || symbol == '\t') {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 0;
            } else if (symbol >= 'a' && symbol <= 'z') {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 9;
            } else if (symbol == 'C') {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 9;
            } else if (symbol >= 'A' && symbol <= 'Z') {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 9;
            } else if (symbol >= '0' && symbol <= '9') {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 9;
            } else if (symbol == '-' || symbol == '+') {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 9;
            }
            break;
        case 10:
            if (isdigit(symbol)) {
                m = (s * 10) - (symbol - '0');
                s = m;
                state = 10;
            } else if (symbol == 'C') {
                f = round(c_f(s));
                l = f;
                r = l;
                state = 3;
            } else if (all(symbol)) {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 2;
            } else if (symbol == ' ' || symbol == '\t') {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 1;
            } else if (symbol == '\n') {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 4;
            } else if (symbol == '-' || symbol == '+') {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 9;
            }
            break;
        case 11:
            if (isdigit(symbol)) {
                m = (s * 10) + (symbol - '0');
                s = m;
                state = 11;
            } else if (symbol == 'C') {
                f = round(c_f(s));
                l = f;
                r = l;
                state = 3;
            } else if (all(symbol)) {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 2;
            } else if (symbol == ' ' || symbol == '\t') {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 1;
            } else if (symbol == '\n') {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 4;
            } else if (symbol == '-' || symbol == '+') {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 9;
            }
            break;
        case 12:
            if (symbol == 'C') {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 0;
            } else if (all(symbol)) {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 2;
            } else if (symbol == ' ' || symbol == '\t') {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 1;
            } else if (symbol == '\n') {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 4;
            } else if (symbol == '-' || symbol == '+') {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 9;
            } else if (isdigit(symbol)) {
                m = (s * 10) + (symbol - '0');
                s = m;
                state = 11;
            }
            break;
        case 13:
            if (symbol == 'C') {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 0;
            } else if (all(symbol)) {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 2;
            } else if (symbol == ' ' || symbol == '\t') {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 0;
            } else if (symbol == '\n') {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 4;
            } else if (symbol == '-') {
                s = 0;
                m = 0;
                f = 0;
                r = 0;
                l = 0;
                state = 8;
            } else if (isdigit(symbol)) {
                m = (s * 10) - (symbol - '0');
                s = m;
                state = 10;
            } else if (symbol == '+') {
                state = 0;
            }
            break;
    }
}
if (r != 0) {
    k = floor(round(r));
    r = k;
    printf("%ld%s", k, "F\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/0XS4H7

Comment: Жесть какая-то. Я же уже писал, как нормально считать. Там только `%d` на `%lf` поменять, не?

Comment: Б-р-р-р... Опишите исходную задачу. Такое ощущение, вы пытаетесь её решать левой ногой через правое ухо :)

Comment: Семь значащих цифр это как раз точность `float`.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/589161/178988

Comment: Откуда вообще это глобальное использование студентами float? Из каких методичек 50-летней давности его вытащили?...

Comment: @Igor, немного оффтоп, но Вы не правы. Точность плавающей арифметики нельзя измерять в количестве десятичных цифр. В ряде случаев (например, минимальное денормализованное число) можно говорить лишь об одной цифре. Короче говоря, там полно особенностей, поэтому будьте осторожнее.

Comment: @Harry, использование float имеет свои преимущества и недостатки, и дело не в 50-ти летней давности, а в том, что в современной системе образования не принято объяснять, что откуда берётся (сам 11 лет преподавал). Принято лишь давать задания и проверять. Например, мало кто объяснить, зачем нужны числа половинной точности (вдвое меньше float), а они ведь нужны.

Comment: @Zealint А можно где-то подробнее? Нет, если для каких-то хитрых аппаратных целей - я понимаю, но вот для общего назначения, так сказать? Где тут float может быть лучше? Как я читал, double еще и быстрее в общем случае?

Comment: @Harry, double не может быть быстрее в общем случае, потому что, например, если данных много и точность не так важна, то в кэш влезет больше float'ов, чем double'оф. Тот же вопрос перемножения матриц, который Вы недавно поднимали: размер блока можно удвоить. Далее, на видеокартах (по поводу совсем новых не знаю, но на обычных точно) float будет работать быстрее. Короче говоря, мне неизвестны случае, чтобы в *нормально написанной* программе double работал быстрее. Короче говоря, нет общего универсального ответа, в каждом случае есть что-то одно, что работает лучше.

Comment: @Zealint Я это прочел в *Optimized C++* Гантерота...

Comment: @Harry, на все эти книги нужно смотреть как на мнение автора. Обычно мнение профессионала высокого класса отличается от мнения авторов подобных книг, но не потому что авторы глупые, а потому что у профессионалов своя специфика задач, им не подходят те вещи, которые подойдут 90%-м людей. Хотя, я не спорю, что *обычно* всё написанное в подобных книгах работает. Я начал разговор с того, что в вузе дают не просто неверную, а часто откровенно ложную информацию о природе вещей. Закончим на этом?

Comment: @Zealint Последний вопрос - вы не хотите задать вопрос об использовании `float` и `double` и самому ответить на него? Думаю, это было бы весьма полезно и поучительно, тем более что в ВУЗах дают зачастую ложную информацию. Лично я почитал бы с большим интересом...

Comment: @Harry, Ваш комментарий очень льстит, но, прошу не думать, что я отношу себя к тем профессионалам высокого класса, о которых сказал. Я собирал информацию на научных конференциях и обращался опыту коллег, но сам мало работал на практике с этими типами. В моей работе, в основном, используется бесконечная точность (как целых, так и дробных чисел). Так что мой ответ, боюсь, будет очень однобоким, он будет вводить читателей в заблуждение. Но в любом случае, спасибо за идею. Может что-то другое напишу.

Comment: @Zealint, разве стандарт плюсов не говорит, что при всех арифметических операциях float расширяется до double, а потом урезается обратно (при необходимости)? UPDATE: Похоже, я неправ: http://ideone.com/4hd2Pw

Comment: @Qwertiy, я что-то не припомню такого места в Стандарте. Далее, обратимся к здравому смыслу: при таком подходе имеем ошибку типа "double-rounding", и, во-вторых, потерю скорости из-за того, что вместо 4-х float он будет перемножать только 2 double одновременно через SSE. Это как-то не согласуется с теми цифрами в экспериментах, что я проводил когда-то давно. Да, вижу, Вы поправили комментарий...

Comment: @Zealint, я с передачей аргументов спутал, кажется.

Answer (score 2):

Не используй `float`. Используй `double`.

Точности float не хватет, чтобы покрыть разницу между этими числами. Плюс, большая погрешность при операциях.

http://codepad.org/XUXBHmVa

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  float x = 44586487;
  float y = 44586489;
  printf("%f %f", x, y);
  return 0;
}
```

```
44586488.000000 44586488.000000
```

Comment: пытался делать через double, все равно та же ситуация